# C# Automapping an array of enums to another while removing duplicates

Tags: c#, automapper

I have two enums. One has more values than the other. I want to map one onto the other while removing missing values.

```
public enum Person1ColoursEnum
{
  BlueColour = 1
  RedColour = 2
}
public enum Person2ColoursEnum
{
  Blue = 1
  Red = 2
  Green = 3
  Yellow = 4
  Pink = 5
}
```

```
var person2Colours = new[] { 
    Person2ColoursEnum.Blue, 
    Person2ColoursEnum.Red, 
    Person2ColoursEnum.Yellow 
}
var favColours = mapper.Map<Person1ColoursEnum[]>(person2Colours);
```

I want the result of this to be [BlueColour, RedColour]

```
CreateMap<Person2ColoursEnum, Person1ColoursEnum>()
    .ConvertUsingEnumMapping(opt => opt
        .MapValue(Person2ColoursEnum.Blue, Person1ColoursEnum.BlueColour )
        .MapValue(Person2ColoursEnum.Red, Person1ColoursEnum.RedColour )
        .MapValue(Person2ColoursEnum.Green, default)
        .MapValue(Person2ColoursEnum.Yellow, default)
        .MapValue(Person2ColoursEnum.Pink, default)
);
```

Closest I can get is with the above which would produce: [BlueColour, RedColour, 0, 0, 0]

Comment: Have you tried to cast default to the correct enum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ to filter out the default values (0) from the resulting array after mapping the enums like this;

`var favColours = mapper.Map<Person1ColoursEnum[]>(person2Colours) .Where(c => c != default);`

This way the `favColours` variable will now contain the desired result of `[BlueColour, RedColour]`.

let me know if this helped

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ to filter the values and then convert them. Here's one approach:

1. Filter the person2Colours array to keep only the values present in `Person1ColoursEnum`.
2. Convert the filtered values from `Person2ColoursEnum` to `Person1ColoursEnum`.

```cs
var person2Colours = new[] { 
    Person2ColoursEnum.Blue, 
    Person2ColoursEnum.Red, 
    Person2ColoursEnum.Yellow 
};

var favColours = person2Colours
    .Where(p2c => Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Person1ColoursEnum), (int)p2c))
    .Select(p2c => (Person1ColoursEnum)(int)p2c)
    .ToArray();
```

This approach has the following benefits:

- It doesn't require any third-party libraries or custom mapping code.
- It's concise and easy to understand.

There are also some drawbacks:

- It relies on the enum values having the same integer values for
  corresponding colours. If the values are different, this approach
  won't work.
- It assumes that the enums have the same underlying type (usually
  `int`). If they have different underlying types, you'll need to cast
  accordingly.

Another approach is to use a dictionary to map the values from one enum to another:

```cs
var person2ToPerson1ColourMap = new Dictionary<Person2ColoursEnum, Person1ColoursEnum>
{
    { Person2ColoursEnum.Blue, Person1ColoursEnum.BlueColour },
    { Person2ColoursEnum.Red, Person1ColoursEnum.RedColour }
};

var favColours = person2Colours
    .Where(p2c => person2ToPerson1ColourMap.ContainsKey(p2c))
    .Select(p2c => person2ToPerson1ColourMap[p2c])
    .ToArray();
```

This approach has the following benefits:

- It doesn't rely on the integer values of the enums being the same.
- It can handle enums with different underlying types.

drawbacks:

- It requires maintaining a separate dictionary for the mapping.
- It's slightly more verbose than the first approach.